# Python can't find libtorchaudio.pyd, despite the file being present in folder

Tags: python, dependencies, runtime, torchaudio

I'm trying to use `pyannote.audio` to transcribe an audio file, however when I try to run the test program that they provided on [their site](https://pypi.org/project/pyannote.audio), the program responds with the error:

```
"FileNotFoundError: Could not find module C:\Users\pedroaf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torchaudio\lib\libtorchaudio.pyd' (or one of its dependencies). Try using 
the full path with constructor syntax.".
```

Despite the file being present at the location.

I tryed uninstalling and reinstalling torchaudio and installing the intel-extension-for-pytorch, but didnt work. Is this a hardware limitation problem? I saw that pytorch uses cuda, which intel has no support.

I tryed also setting up a conda environment but it returns the same error when trying to run it.

Sorry if I'm not giving enough information, I'm not even sure on what I should provide for more context